# Adding anchor tag in outlook email using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, email, outlook

in my project, i opened the outlook email when user click on send email button in web app.Email opened as predefined subject and body which i achieved using through the javascript. now the client want me to add a anchor tag , that will redirect the user to a website eg :

`<a href="www.xyz.com"></a>`

but the email engine doesn't render it as html content instead it render it as plain text. I have to done it through code, so that client can see the email before sending so using back-end technology is of no use.
This is simple task, but i'm facing many problems. i have feeling that someone should have achieved it somehow. please share the idea or solution. client is very pissed and i'm having hard time.

here is the plunkr :-
plnkr.co/edit/N5G5PR1SujIvmyLglSTs?p=preview

Comment: how are you creating the message body?? It must be in html format too right?

Comment: can we have more/full code? lorem ipsum it if you must? have you tried just writing the extra bit as plain text and making it a link through outlook?

Comment: @KeithAnderson out of SO , what does `lorem ipsum` mean?? I see this all over in sample templates and websites. What language is it?

Comment: It is Latin and is "dummy" or "placeholder" text. by `lorem ipsum it` I meant to take out all of the sensitive or copyrighted information and replace it with dummy text.

Comment: hi, i have created a plunker, this is overview how i achieved the functionality.
https://plnkr.co/edit/N5G5PR1SujIvmyLglSTs?p=preview

user can click on the button, email will open, but the anchor tags or any other html tags are not rendering, instead they render as plain text.

Comment: @Reddy , initially that was text, but when i tried to enter  the html,  it was not working as expected. i know that is for security reason, but there should be a way so that we can enter the rich html content using the javasciprt.

Comment: Its would be easier for people here if you can provide the code which you have used to achieve this?

Comment: You can use mozillas email client to send the rich HTML and it renders perfectly in Gmail and the mozilla client.

Comment: @reddy please find the plunker thatbi have attached..

Comment: @Reddy please find the plunker thatbi have attached

Comment: Those who are searching for the same solution, please don't waste time. It is impossible to render the anchor or html tags using mailto as it render the input into plain text.
I said the same to client, and working on alternative solution.